# Unable to send emails in Laravel using Swift Mailer - proc_open() function disabled by the provider

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

My web host disabled **proc_open** function in php and I can't send emails anymore.

I get this error log:

```
> proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons
```

I use laravel default Swiftmailer.
What can I do?

Comment: which operating system do you use??

Comment: What mail driver to you use, what is your mail configuration?

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=localhost MAIL_PORT=25 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`proc_open` should only be required when Swiftmailer is using an external executable, like sendmail.  You should still be able to use a different transport like SMTP, Mailgun, or [one of the other drivers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail) described in the docs.

As a test, try using the SMTP driver, and just entering your own SMTP mail details - whatever you use to send mail from your mail client.  Try the following in your `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=your.smtp.host // (copy from your mail client)
MAIL_PORT=your.smtp.port // (copy from your mail client)
MAIL_USERNAME=your.smtp.username // (copy from your mail client)
MAIL_PASSWORD=your.smtp.password // (copy from your mail client)
```

This is probably not suitable for a permanent solution but will let you test that you can send mail without proc_open.  I use the free tier of Mailgun and can recommend it.

Comment: I'm still getting proc_open error even with smtp any ideas? here is my .env details:

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername
MAIL_PASSWORD='mypasswordwithspecialcharacters'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed As my answer says, you will only get that error when an external executable is being used.  So, if your `.env` says `smtp` and that is not being used, where would you look? `config/mail.php` of course! Check the driver specified in `.env` is really in use, eg `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER')`.

Answer (score 2):

Check and changes are your `php.ini` has this line.

```
disable_functions = exec,system,dl,passthru,chown,shell_exec,popen,proc_open
```

Check this a list of functions disabled by safe mode [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php).

**UPDATE**
Once you found that, follow below instruction:
Remove the **proc_open** from the disable_functions at `php.ini` file

*OR*

Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't have an access/right to do that.

Comment: I called phpinfo() and searched proc_open(). Here is the result:

disable_functions: dl, system, passthru, kill, virtual, http_connect, connect, link, popen, ... , openlog, shell_exec, exec, **proc_open**

Comment: I asked my host. I recieved this answer: **This function is not enabled, we will not turn it back on for security reasons.**

Comment: So can I use swiiftmailer without proc_open?

Comment: @robcaa: Sorry, I haven't any idea about that but you can ask your second question at [swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @robcaa You can accept/upvote this, if you fond like answer/solution/help...:)

Comment: Why would someone REMOVE proc_open from disallowed functions !? Please do not induce in error people, that is a very risky function and should not be used.

Comment: `proc_open` is necessary for the php `mail()` function to send emails.

Comment: @robcaa my server boys wont allow that function, i'm using smtp drivers and i'm still getting the same error, did you solve this ?