# Sending mail with Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to send mail from my website.

I'm using laravel 5.5 and the shared hosting of hostnet.nl.

I'm very sure i have all my configuration correct..

My .env :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp02.hostnet.nl
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

But when i try to send mail this allways returns

Whoops there was an error:

`proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons`

I already chat with the hosting company and they said this is not a php setting that is allowed to be changed. So i cannot enable this.

When i try to set `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` it says connection refused.

I have another laravel installation/website at this shared hosting, which has the same `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` and this works perfectly.

This installation is on laravel 5.2.*

Is this something that has changed inside swiftmailer from laravel 5.2 to 5.5?

I don't know how to fix this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `connection refused` is a network level error. Either the host address of the server is incorrect, or your shared hosting provider is explicitly fire-walling your packets. According to this [port checker](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), the host you have provided is open and listening on port 587, the SMTP port. You probably will not be able to use this shared hosting provider for your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send emails in Laravel using Swift Mailer - proc\_open() function disabled by the provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854659/unable-to-send-emails-in-laravel-using-swift-mailer-proc-open-function-disab)

Comment: Sometimes shared hosting may require additional fields. It's a good idea to add MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS and MAIL_FROM_NAME fields to .env config

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try changing this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
```

There is no "mail" driver for laravel's mailing service (Laravel 5.5), you could have problems with the "smtp" because of wrong credentials. I think Laravel 5.2 might be using php's built-in "mail()" function when the "mail" driver is set, which could work on some shared hosting and fail on other.

Most shared hosting providers allow sending via the default server "sendmail" so you could also try this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

If you can't get "sendmail" or "smtp" to work, you could try the "mailgun" or any other external mail service provider. Mailgun for example gives you 10 000 free mails per month so you will not need any paid subscriptions and the set-up tutorials are very easy, plus you have great tools for monitoring the sent mails.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Mailgun advertises with 10.000 free emails every month but only after you give them your Credit card information and that is something i don't like to do. By the way the `sendmail` mail driver returns the same `proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons
`. I cant get the SMTP to work either tho i'm 100% sure i have the correct information. I'm stuck with my hands in my hair.

Comment: If this one doesn't work you still have few other choices:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kristian Lilov . you saved my day! i have hosted in A2hosting. your solution worked for me.