# Laravel: Mail send error due to proc_open()

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel Framework on Shared Server for running ecommerce system, I am getting following error during mail sending.

```
(1/1) ErrorException

proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons
in StreamBuffer.php (line 295)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons', '/home/--hidden--/public_html/shop/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php', 295, array('command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs', 'descriptorSpec' => array(array('pipe', 'r'), array('pipe', 'w'), array('pipe', 'w')), 'pipes' => array()))
```

Is there any other way to send mail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending mail with Laravel on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291048/sending-mail-with-laravel-on-shared-hosting)

Comment: @aynber There are no answers found for using default local mailing system instead of smtp's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a shared server many times the functions that manipulate the system not working by security questions.

Laravel allows that you use many drivers like SMTP, Mailgun, Sparkpost, SES and others.

You can use Mailgun, it's a good tool for send transactional emails.

But the easier way to send email is using a SMTP account like Gmail, just configure your .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I hope help you.