# i could not run artisan schedule:run cron command at shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

I want to achieve task scheduling in my laravel 5.8 project. For that, I have created a custom artisan command `artisan send: credentials` which send emails to specific users based on their status.

**sendUserCredentials.php**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Mail\credentialsEmail;
use App\Models\userModel;
use Mail;

class sendUserCredentials extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'send:credentials';


    protected $description = 'Credentials send Successfully!';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
       $users = userModel::select(["email","username","role","id"])->where("credentials","NO")->get();
       foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
           Mail::to($user->email)->send(new credentialsEmail($user));
           userModel::where("id",$user->id)->update(["credentials"=>"SEND"]);
       }

    }
}
```

I added this command in kernel.php so that I can run this command using the laravel task scheduler.

**kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        Commands\sendUserCredentials::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('send:credentials')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

so on my local server, everything works like a charm when I run this command `php artisan schedule:run`
but on the shared server when I run scheduler using the cron command `*****/path/to/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` it gives me an error like this

```
local.ERROR: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\LogicException(code: 0): The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation. at /path/to/vendor/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:143)
```

**BUT** when I run the artisan command directly `*****/path/to/project/artisan send:credentials >> /dev/null 2>&1` using the cron job then there is no error and emails send successfully!

Comment: Talk with your service provider and install the dependencies

Comment: but the service provider asks that he could not install `proc_open` due to security reasons.

Comment: only way is change service provider

Comment: what php version u are using?

Comment: @Dlk I'm using PHP version 7.2

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30054#issuecomment-544228901

Comment: Change php version to 7.3 and than see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855691/12232340 this not a new issue in laravel I hear it about 5 years ago, shared hostings wont activate some functions becuase of security reason like `mail();` , proc_open and more, you can use alternate methods to send emails like SMTP, Mailgun, Mandril etc.. See more https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to send emails in Laravel using Swift Mailer - proc\_open() function disabled by the provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854659/unable-to-send-emails-in-laravel-using-swift-mailer-proc-open-function-disab)

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is not the mail. because emails can be sent when I hit the artisan command directly.
I think the issue is in the task scheduler which is using the proc_open dependency

Comment: If you can send mails through calling any shell script, but cannot when running the request through a browser, you should check the `php.ini` about this - as the linked question tells you. If you think that the problem lies in some other part of Laravel, please identify the part in question. Nobody can guess what kind of code is used within your commands - I had assume that `mail` is the culprit, as you use it?

Comment: @NicoHaase above I share all of my code please have a look. again I'm clearing that emails send successfully if I run the artisan command directly using the cron job **BUT** when I put the same artisan command in the laravel task scheduler and run the scheduler using the cron job then it gives me this particular error.

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel 5.8 and deployed my website on namecheap shared hosting. Following command help me to execute cron job properly:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/YOUR_USER/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /home/YOUR_USER/public_html/cronjobs.txt
```

As namecheap allow minimum of 5 min interval, so above command will execute after 5 min and output will be displayed in a text file.

Answer (score -2):

The Error

```
The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.
```

is because of Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode. To solve this please follow the steps shared below.

Add the File /config/flare.php and add the below content

```
'reporting' => [
    'anonymize_ips' => true,
    'collect_git_information' => false,
    'report_queries' => true,
    'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
    'report_query_bindings' => true,
    'report_view_data' => true,
],
```

And Clear the Bootstrap cache with below command

```
php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear
```

Most probably the issue will be solved. Otherwise check once [this link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30054#issuecomment-534471490)

Comment: flare.php file does not exist in laravel 5.8.it is introduced with an ignition package which is in laravel 6.0.

Comment: The error is regarding Mail and Symfony. You can read the shared links and try the solutions. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30054#issuecomment-534471490

Check point 7th https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400

Comment: Please add all relevant information for resolving that issue to your question. Don't use external links as the only information

Comment: Sorry @NicoHaase but this is the solution as per the Question. As per the shared problem the answer may differ and all the possible ways i can't mention here. 
But i have fully tried to mention all the steps which will solve the above problem.

Comment: No. Linking to external sources instead of putting all information in the answer itself is never a solution. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @NicoHaase I have changed my Answer. Please check if it is helpful

Comment: Its better - but you should add some explanation to it such that others can understand **why** these changes are neccessary